# Possible to restore multiple windows (of the same document) between sessions in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, workflow

Is it possible to restore multiple windows of the same document between sessions?

In other words:

1. Open a document.
2. Select `Window` > `Arrange` > `New Window for …document's name` ( <kbd>^</kbd> <kbd>⌥</kbd> <kbd>⌘</kbd> <kbd>N</kbd> on Mac )
3. Close the document.
4. Re-open the document.
5. (… multiple windows state gone.)

Answer (score 1):

I've never bumped into any documentation indicating that you could.

( I do wish I'm wrong about this cause I've tried to find out the answer to this very question myself but I never found a way that you could preserve it.. )

I'd really like it if I could save the window state in every document maybe.. The position and any extra windows. Cause it is also a hassle to start moving it to another screen and so on.